# How to calculate top and left positions of a centered div?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

The question is a bit more complicated than the title, I'm trying to get the top and left values of a centered div that use these css attributes :

```
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
```

I am able to get the top and left values without any issue, but I don't understand how `translate(-50%, -50%)` behaves for the forumla below.

try Fiddle to test : https://jsfiddle.net/nqym3s4b/

```
...
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">...</div>
</div>
```

---

```
var div = document.querySelector('#div2');

var w = div.offsetWidth, 
    h = div.offsetHeight;

// top & left
var lw = (w / 100) * 50,
    lh = (h / 100) * 50;

// top & left with transform(-50%, -50%)
var tw = (lw / 100) * 50,
    th = (lh / 100) * 50;

left = 'left: ' + tw + 'px;';
top = 'top: ' + th + 'px;';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`translate` will consider the `width`/`height` of the **inner** element, so 50% is half the width/height of the translated element unlike `top`/`left` that will consider the dimension of the **parent** element.

The calculation is a simple addition of both values *(I added a third div over the `#div2` so you can see the result)*

```js
var div1 = document.querySelector('#div1'); //parent element
var div2 = document.querySelector('#div2'); //translated element

var w1 = div1.offsetWidth,
    h1 = div1.offsetHeight;

var w2 = div2.offsetWidth,
    h2 = div2.offsetHeight;


var lw = (w1 / 100) * 50 + (-w2 / 100) * 50,
    lh = (h1 / 100) * 50 + (-h2 / 100) * 50;


document.querySelector('#left').innerHTML = 'left: ' + lw + 'px;';
document.querySelector('#top').innerHTML = 'top: ' + lh + 'px;';

document.querySelector('#div3').style.left = lw + 'px';
document.querySelector('#div3').style.top = lh + 'px';
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 560px;
  height: 240px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

#div1 #div2 {
  width: 340px;
  height: 120px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#div1 #div3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <span id="left"></span>
    <br>
    <span id="top"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <!-- to compare -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have taken this picture from [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate). It shows how the CSS translate property works. Basically, HTML work as follows: the origin remains on the top left-hand corner of the element, `x` axes right and `y` axes goes down

The property takes a two-dimensional vector as parameter (`x` and `y`) and moves the whole element in the direction defined by the vector.

[image]

Comment: `and moves the top left corner in the direction and norm of the vector.` --> it moves the whole element not only the top/left corner. It's a vector applied to each point of element ... so it's not totally true to say `it moves the top left corner`